# How was Tamahome able to get out of the book The Universe of the Four Gods?

Tags: fushigi-yugi

In the last episode of Fushigi Yugi, it was shown that

> Tamahome was able to get out of the book of The Universe of the Four Gods and was able to go to Miaka's world.

How was he able to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the last episode of the anime (i.e. episode 52):

> After Miaka uses up her three wishes, Suzaku grants her wish that she and Tamahome are together forever. But, this wish cannot be completely granted because it goes against the rule that characters in *The Universe of the Four Gods* cannot be together with people from the real world. Suzaku brings Tamahome into the real world as a separate being named Taka.

This is further expanded on and fully resolved in the OVA (and manga):

> Taka doesn't have his memories as Tamahome because Suzaku sealed them in a duplicate figure called 'Tamahome' in *The Universe of the Four Gods*. At the end of the OVA, Taka and the 'Tamahome' from inside the book merge into the final 'Taka', who now has all of the memories from the original Fushigi Yugi Series.

And that's how Tamahome comes out of *The Universe of the Four Gods*

Comment: Wasn't Miaka's last wish to have everything ok? (since the world was devastated by Nakago?)

Comment: You are correct. I had forgotten that the second wish was to seal Seiryu and the last was to restore the world (it's been a while since I've seen/read the series). Suzaku granted Miaka/Tamahome's wish to be together, but the same rules applied (book characters can't be with real world people), which is where Taka came from.